# Issue with DupelicateEntry, /DragAndDropPermissionCompat.class

Tags: android

I have used couple of image based libraries, like imageFilter, ImagePicker, imageCropper, but this leads to an **error of possile duplication**, not able to build an apk. I have excluded the support-v4 and support-v13 but nothing worked, here is my `build.gradle(Module:app) script:`

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.android.support:design:24.0.0'){
     exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
    }
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0"
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.1'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.zomato:androidphotofilters:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.lyft:scissors:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: why you have added `com.android.support:design:24.0.0` and `com.android.support:design:27.0.2` both?

Comment: Why are you having `design:24.0.0` and `design:27.0.2` . Also there are mixed versions always use same version, use `27.1.0` for every support libraries.

Comment: Its giving same error after removing the duplicate entries @OmInfowaveDevelopers

Comment: @Ibrahim, can you point those unnecessary please?

Comment: @kashifahmad update latest gradle and error

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers i was using  {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'} updating it to latest worked. Thank you all for your prompt responses.

Comment: try excluding module from top 4 libs compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove duplicate dependencies and keep the same version for all  dependencies

```
dependencies {
        compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.31.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.31.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.31.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
        //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0"
        compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
        compile 'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:1.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.1'
        compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
        compile 'com.github.zomato:androidphotofilters:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.1'
        compile 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
        compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"
        compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
        compile 'com.lyft:scissors:1.1.1'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```